# HA kubernetes cluster: Accidental kubeadm reset on 1 master node, connection refused when rejoining the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have setup a kubernetes cluster with 2 master nodes (cp01 192.168.1.42, cp02 192.168.1.46) and 4 worker nodes, implemented with haproxy and keepalived running as static pods in the cluster, internal etcd cluster. For some silly reasons, I accidentally kubeadm reset -f on cp01. Now I am trying rejoin the cluster using kubeadm join command but I keep getting the dial tcp 192.168.1.49:8443: connect: connection refused, where 192.168.1.49 is the LoadBalancer IP. Please help! Below are the current configurations.

**/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg on cp02**

```
defaults
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
frontend apiserver
    bind *.8443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    default_backend apiserver
backend apiserver
    option httpchk GET /healthz
    http-check expect status 200
    mode tcp
    option ssl-hello-chk
    balance roundrobin
        default-server inter 10s downinter 5s rise 2 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 250 maxqueue 256 weight 100
        #server master01 192.168.1.42:6443 check     ***the one i accidentally resetted
        server master02 192.168.1.46:6443 check
```

**/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf on cp02**

```
global_defs {
    router_id LVS_DEVEL
    script_user root
    enable_script_security
    dynamic_interfaces
}
vrrp_script check_apiserver {
    script "/etc/keepalived/check_apiserver.sh"
    interval 3
    weight -2
    fall 10
    rise 2
}
vrrp_instance VI_l {
    state BACKUP
    interface ens192
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 101
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass ***
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.49/24
    }
    track_script {
        check_apiserver
    }
}
```

**cluster kubeadm-config**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
    ClusterConfiguration: |
        apiServer:
            extraArgs:
                authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
            timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
        apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
        certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
        clusterName: kubernetes
        controlPlaneEndpoint: 192.168.1.49:8443
        controllerManager: {}
        dns:
            type: CoreDNS
        etcd:
            local:
                dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
        imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
        kind: ClusterConfiguration
        kubernetesVersion: v1.19.2
        networking:
            dnsDomain: cluster.local
            podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
            serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
        scheduler: {}
    ClusterStatus: |
        apiEndpoints:
            cp02:
                advertiseAddress: 192.168.1.46
                bindPort: 6443
        apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
        kind: ClusterStatus
...
```

**kubectl cluster-info**

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.1.49:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.1.49:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

**More Info**

1. cluster was initialised with --upload-certs on cp01.
2. I drained and deleted cp01 from the cluster.
3. `kubeadm join --token ... --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash ... --control-plane --certificate-key ...` command returned:

   ```
   error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get "https://192.168.1.49:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config?timeout=10s": dial tcp 192.168.1.49:8443: connect: connection refused
   ```
4. `kubectl exec -n kube-system -it etcd-cp02 -- etcdctl --endpoints=https://192.168.1.46:2379 --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt member list` returned:

   ```
   ..., started, cp02, https://192.168.1.46:2380, https://192.168.1.46:2379, false
   ```
5. `kubectl describe pod/etcd-cp02 -n kube-system`:

   ```
   ...
   Container ID: docker://...
   Image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
   Image ID: docker://...
   Port: <none>
   Host Port: <none>
   Command:
     etcd
     --advertise-client-urls=https://192.168.1.46:2379
     --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
     --client-cert-auth=true
     --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
     --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://192.168.1.46:2380
     --initial-cluster=cp01=https://192.168.1.42:2380,cp02=https://192.168.1.46:2380
     --initial-cluster-state=existing
     --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
     --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://192.168.1.46:2379
     --listen-metrics-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2381
     --listen-peer-urls=https://192.168.1.46:2380
     --name=cp02
     --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
     --peer-client-cert-auth=true
     --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key
     --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
     --snapshot-count=10000
     --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
     ...
   ```
6. Tried copying the certs to `cp01:/etc/kubernetes/pki` before running
   `kubeadm join 192.168.1.49:8443 --token ... --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash` but returned same error.

   ```
   # files copied over to cp01
   ca.crt
   ca.key
   sa.key
   sa.pub
   front-proxy-ca.crt
   front-proxy-ca.key
   etcd/ca.crt
   etcd/ca.key
   ```

**Troubleshoot network**

1. Able to ping 192.168.1.49 on cp01
2. `nc -v 192.168.1.49 8443` on cp01 returned `Ncat: Connection refused.`
3. `curl -k https://192.168.1.49:8443/api/v1...` works on cp02 and worker nodes (returns code 403 which should be normal).
4. /etc/cni/net.d/ is removed on cp01
5. Manually cleared iptables rules on cp01 with 'KUBE' or 'cali'.
6. firewalld is disabled on both cp01 and cp02.
7. I tried joining with a new server cp03 192.168.1.48 and encountered the same dial tcp 192.168.1.49:8443: connect: connection refused error.
8. `netstat -tlnp | grep 8443` on cp02 returned:

   ```
   tcp    0    0.0.0.0:8443    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 27316/haproxy
   ```
9. `nc -v 192.168.1.46 6443` on cp01 and cp03 returns:

   ```
   Ncat: Connected to 192.168.1.46:6443
   ```

Any advice/guidance would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss here. I'm thinking it might be due to the network rules on cp02 but I don't really know how to check this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was the issue when I entered `ip a`. Realised that ens192 on cp01 still contains the secondary ip address 192.168.1.49.

Simply `ip addr del 192.168.1.49/24 dev ens192` and `kubeadm join...` and cp01 is able to rejoin the cluster successfully. Can't believe I missed that...